# Safe usage of std::is_constant_evaluated in constructor/destructor?

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr

Let's image I want to have a C-style string wrapper class with a constructor from `std::string_view`:

- Runtime -> copy char array to wrapper
- Compile-time -> copy pointer to char array (it's a literal so it's safe to just copy the pointer?)

The same logic happens in the destructor:

- Runtime -> delete char array
- Compile-time -> do nothing (or set pointer to `nullptr`)

To detect compile-time and runtime, `std::is_constant_evaluated()` is used.
Is this safe? Are there edge cases, which can cause problems?

### Example implementation

```cpp
class String {
public:
    constexpr String() noexcept = default;

    explicit constexpr String(std::string_view str) {
        copy(str.data(), str.size());
    }

    constexpr String(const String& other) {
        copy(other.data(), other.size());
    }

    constexpr String(String&& other) noexcept
        : data_(std::exchange(other.data_, nullptr)),
          size_(std::exchange(other.size_, 0)) {}

    constexpr ~String() {
        clear();
    }

    constexpr String& operator=(const String& other) {
        clear();
        copy(other.data(), other.size());
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr String& operator=(String&& other) noexcept {
        data_ = std::exchange(other.data_, nullptr);
        size_ = std::exchange(other.size_, 0);
        return *this;
    }

    // ...

    constexpr const char* data() const noexcept { return data_; }
    constexpr size_t size() const noexcept { return size_; }

private:
    constexpr void clear() {
        size_ = 0;
        if (std::is_constant_evaluated()) {
            data_ = nullptr;
        } else {
            delete[] data_;
        }
    }

    constexpr void copy(const char* data, size_t size) {
        if (std::is_constant_evaluated()) {
            data_ = const_cast<char*>(data);
        } else {
            data_ = new char[size];
            std::copy(data, data + size, data_);
        }
        size_ = size;
    }

    char* data_{nullptr};
    size_t size_{0};
};
```

Link to compiler explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/xeT9WfKrn

Comment: Why are you reimplementing `std::string_view` using `std::string_view`? Also you cannot modify `constexpr` objects. So `constexpr clear` etc make no sense.

Comment: @AjinkyaKamat It totally makes sense, because then you can use it in a constexpr context, even if the object itself is not constexpr.

Comment: But OPs `String` class is obviously not the same as `std::string_view`.

Comment: @chrysante I have been saying `std::string_view` my bad. I meant `std::string`. It is already `constexpr` since `C++20`

Comment: This is String class is just an example. Since C++20 destructors can be `constexpr` and also `new`/`delete` can be used in `constexpr` contexts. Therefore I don't see a problem defining a class with a cleanup logic in the destructor.

Comment: Do you have mutable public functions? if yes, they won't be usable on non-constexpr instance, IN contant expression. i.e `consteval void foo() {  String s; s.mutate(); }`.

Comment: @luxderfux: "*it's a literal so it's safe to just copy the pointer?*" You don't know that it's a literal. A compile-time string could also be a stack character array.

Comment: Very good point @NicolBolas! I didn't think about that.. this invalidates the whole concept. Any idea how to detect literals and avoid the copy?

Comment: @luxderfux: No. There is no way in standard C++ to know that a given `char const*` points to a string literal. The absolute most that you can do is make a `consteval` UDL function that you use on specific literals to identify them to your system, but even those can be called manually (though obviously not by accident).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't actually guarantee that `std::is_constant_evaluated()` will be `true` in the destructor if it is `true` in the constructor.

Here's the first example I thought of:

```cpp
consteval String s() {
    return String("123");
}

int main() {
    String str(s());  // Does not allocate
    // On destructor: Invalid delete
}
```

And the next suspicious functions are the move constructor / move assign operator, where you don't know if `other` is a compile-time string if it is being called at runtime (e.g., with the `consteval` function above, `str = s();`).

Though a `String` constructed during constant evaluation is unlikely to be exposed at runtime as a non-`const` object. It is either gone or a subobject of a `constexpr` object, which will be `const`, so this is unlikely to be an issue (since your copy constructor/copy assign operator work as expected between runtime and compile time).

---

(The rest of this answer does not strictly answer your question. But it might solve your original problem)

But there's an easier way to do what you want: At runtime use `std::string` and at compile time use `std::string`. The only issue is that `std::string` can't be stored as a `constexpr` variable, but in that specific scenario use a `std::string_view` if you can, or use a class like this if your string is more complicated:

```cpp
template<std::size_t N>
struct String {
    template<std::invocable F>
    explicit constexpr String(F&& f) {
        auto copied = std::string_view(std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f))).copy(data, N);
        std::fill(data + copied, std::end(data), '\0');
    }

    constexpr operator std::string_view() const noexcept {
        return { data, data + N };
    }

    char data[N + 1];
};

template<std::invocable F>
String(F) -> String<std::string_view(std::invoke(F())).size()>;

// Replace:
// inline constexpr std::string s(std::string("123") + "456");
// With a no-arg captureless lambda:
inline constexpr String s([]{
    return std::string("123") + "456";
});
static_assert(std::string_view{s} == "123456");

constexpr std::string make(int x) { /*...*/; }
// Replace:
// inline constexpr std::string s2(make(4));
// With:
inline constexpr String s2([]{ return make(4); });
```

This class will also copy string literals but it swaps one `const char[N+1]` with another so you don't end up using any more memory.